# Can't get sdcard real path on Android 6.0

Tags: android, android-sdcard

My android phone is Sony Z3, and the version is Android 6.0.1, when I use 
`Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)` to get the SDCard DCIM path, which returns path is `/storage/emulated/0/DCIM`,

but my sdcard real path is `/storage/3FC5-160A/DCIM`. Any one know how to get the correct sdcard path on Android 6? Thanks.

Also, I have add the external storage read and write permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 2):

I had to do this specifically for M. Get all the dirs with `context.getExternalCacheDirs()` then check if it's removable

```
// For Marshmallow, use getExternalCacheDirs() instead of System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE")
// to determine if there are mounted SD cards
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
     File[] externalCacheDirs = context.getExternalCacheDirs();
     for (File file : externalCacheDirs) {
         if (Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable(file)) {
               // Path is in format /storage.../Android....
               // Get everything before /Android
               externalSdCardPath = file.getPath().split("/Android")[0];
               break;
         }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I used the same method with you, context.getExternalMediaDirs() can also get the real sdcard path.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of research I found a solution. Code at below gives you the path in *"SD card/Android/data/your app location "* then you can do whatever you want.

```
getApplicationContext().getExternalCacheDirs()[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

use `getExternalStorageDirectory()` instead of `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` like below

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM + "/";
```

or check path first

```
final String path = android.os.Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it still returns the emulated path.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the access storage framework. I get it by handling the string of uri and get the "3FC5-160A" part and then combine it to the sdcard path.

You can check my detailed answer here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38648200/6530106