# Can not locate the sdcard file(not hard code) in android 6.0

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-sdcard, mobile-development

Since android 6.0, the sdcard path is no longer "/storage/sdcard1/", "/storage/sdcard-ext/" or something.

The path depends on the phone instead. If I use Nexus 5x AVD, the path is "/storage/1D15-3A1B/". When I use Nexus 6p AVD, the path is "/storage/4679-1802/". So how can I dynamically write the sdcard path in program to locate the file in external sdcard?

Thank you!

Comment: Isn't Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(); working anymore?

Comment: @Frame91 is correct.  You should never have been using any of those paths, it has ALWAYS depended on the phone.  Those aren't even the most common paths before 6.0, if you were using those you failed on most devices.

Comment: Never rely on hardcoded paths!

Comment: @Frame91 Yeah. Sorry I didn't make it clear...That only locates to the "/storage/emulated/0/" path. It's external storage. But I wanted to ask the second external storage path or removable sdcard path.

Comment: @Rotwang That's true. There are so many android facories, and every one of them are quite different...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `getExternalFilesDirs()`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I looked into this function. But it still returns to the "emulated" path...

Comment: It will return an array of paths. The second item is path to SD card. It is really ...FilesDirs not ...FilesDir.

Comment: I just read this comment. Yeah, `getExternalFilesDirs()` is much easier to do that...I mistook for `getExternalFilesDir()` instead! @greenapps

Comment: This is THE way for Android 6 and above. And often for Android 5.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I found the solution.

I'm using the access storage framework. I get it by handling the string of uri and get the "1D15-3A1B" part and then combine it to the sdcard path. Here is the solution.

1. When I click the file `Welcome to Word.docx` in the sdcard root path, I get the `intent` by `onActivityResult()`.
2. Get the DocumentId by `String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(intent.getData())`, thus the string `docId` is `"1D15-3A1B:Welcome to Word.docx"`.
3. Split the string and get a string array by `String[] split = docId.split(":")`, so we can get `"1D15-3A1B"` which is `split[0]`, and the path in sdcard `"Welcome to Word.docx"` is `split[1]`.
4. If we want to get the uri of the file we clicked before, just need to build a new string `String newPath = "/storage/" + split[0] + "/" + split[1]`.

update:
Actually `getExternalFilesDirs()` is much easier to do this...Thank you @greenapps!

Comment: @greenapps sry I'm new here... I'll edit the solution right now.

Comment: If you had looked with a file explorer in /storage you would have seen it.

Comment: @greenapps yeah...It's actually easy to figure out. I wanted to find a way get the `"1D15-3A1B"` and not to hard code.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying many approaches, including:

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

Still my picture files in DCIM/Camera were not visible to my app. I could see the directory names, but listFiles() on any of these directories returned null.
Finally, and sheepishly, I found that my Manifest did not contain the magic line android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. 
Once I added the permission, it worked like a charm.

Moral of the story: Android does not warn/break/throw exception under this condition. When it fails, it fails silently!